# Buffer overrun with STL vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am copying the contents of one STL vector to another. 
The program is something like this

```
std::vector<uint_8>  l_destVector(100); //Just for illustration let us take the size as 100.
std::vector<uint_8>  l_sourceVector; //Let us assume that source vector is already populated.

memcpy( l_destVector.data(), l_sourceVector.data(), l_sourceVector.size() );
```

The above example is pretty simplistic but in my actual code the size 
of destination vector is dynamically calculated. 
Also the source vector is getting populated dynamically making it possible to have different length of data. 
Hence it increases the chance of buffer overrun.

The problem I faced is my program is not crashing at the point of `memcpy` when there is a buffer overrun but sometime later making it hard to debug.

How do we explain this behavior?

/******************************************************************************************************/
Based on the responses I am editing the question to make my concern more understandable.

So, this is a legacy code and there are lot of places where vector has been copied using memcpy, and we do not intend to change the existing code. My main concern here is **"Should memcpy not guarantee immediate crash, if not why ?"**, I would honestly admit that this is not very well written code.

**A brief illustration of actual use is as follows.**

In the below method, i_DDRSPDBuffer and i_dataDQBuffer where generated based on some logic in the calling method.

o_dataBuffer was assigned a memory space that would have been sufficient to take the data from two input buffers, but some recent changes in method that calls updateSPDDataToRecordPerDimm, is causing overrun in one of the flows.

```
typedef std::vector<uint8_t> DataBufferHndl;
errHdl_t updateSPDDataToRecordPerDimm(
        dimmContainerIterator_t i_spdMmap,
        const DataBufferHndl & i_DDRSPDBuffer,
        const DataBufferHndl & i_dataDQBuffer,
        DataBufferHndl & o_dataBuffer) 

{

uint16_t l_dimmSPDBytes = (*i_spdMmap).second.dimmSpdBytes;

// Get the Data Buffer Handle for the input and output vectors
uint8_t * l_pOutLDimmSPDData = o_dataBuffer.data();
const uint8_t * l_pInDDRSPDData = i_DDRSPDBuffer.data();
const uint8_t * l_pInDQData = i_dataDQBuffer.data();


memcpy(l_pOutLDimmSPDData, l_pInDDRSPDData, l_dimmSPDBytes);
memcpy(l_pOutLDimmSPDData + l_dimmSPDBytes,
    l_pInDQData, LDIMM_DQ_DATA_BYTES);

memcpy(l_pOutLDimmSPDData ,
       l_pInDQData, LDIMM_DQ_DATA_BYTES); ====> Expecting the crash here but the crash happens some where after the method updateSPDDataToRecordPerDimm returns.

}
```

Comment: Show minimal verified example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: it "crashes" presumably because you don't limit the destination vector based on the "size" of the source vector. Therefore - later when you come to use the data in destination, you *think* you have 100 bytes, but infact you may have more or less - if it's more, it's most likely overwriting some other state, of if it's less, your logic for handling the data barfs due to the extra crap.

Comment: To copy the contents from one vector to another, by far the easiest way is `l_destVector = l_sourceVector;`.

Comment: Show us exception string.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to crash, it's undefined behaviour.

If you had used `std::copy` instead with `std::vector<uint_8>::iterator`s in debug mode, you probably would've hit an assertion which would've caught it.

Comment: OK.. If safety concern has been taken care of, will memcpy not be faster, as compared to using iterartors?

Comment: @ManishChowdhary: `memcpy` generally is *slower*, not faster. `memcpy` has to copy anything. Could be unaligned, could have odd lengths. In comparison, `std::copy` is a template and separately instantiated for each case. Now here `std::copy`  is instantiated similar to how `memcpy`works, for `uint_8`, so in this case they're probably equally slow.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't crash right at the moment of memcpy because you 'only' overwrite the memory behind the allocated vector. As long as your program does not read from that corrupt memory and use the data, your program will continue to run.

As already mentioned before, using memcpy is not the recommended way to copy the contents of stl containers. You'd be on the safe side with

std::copy
std::vector::assign

And in both cases you'd also get the aforementioned iterator debugging which will trigger close to the point where the error actually is.

Comment: If there is no grant for read from memory page, there is no grant to wright there. So, it's almost impossible to write somewhere and then get exception on read, except if someone set specific privileges on memory page.

Comment: True, the actual read wouldn't cause an exception. But the data that is read is corrupt, which in turn will eventually cause errors in the program. But thanx for the input, I clarified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that! It will eventually bite you.

Use either `std::copy` and and `output_iterator`, or since you know the size of the destination, `resize` the vector to the correct size or create a vector of the correct size and pipe the contents straight in, or simply the assignment operator.